# Bitmap and mat color

Tags: android, opencv, colors, bitmap, mat

I have 4 Mat that need to be in grayscale because otherwise the method Core.add () does not work.
it only accepts arrays with a channel. 
once this is done i can not bring back the colored mat. 
can someone help me? 
it is true that core.add () takes only 1 channel?
background,foreground,mask and dst are Mat.

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(background , background , Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(foreground , foreground , Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(dst , dst , Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Core.add(background, foreground, dst, mask); // new image output

Imgproc.cvtColor(background , background , Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);
Imgproc.cvtColor(foreground , foreground , Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);
Imgproc.cvtColor(dst , dst , Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA);
Imgproc.cvtColor(mask , mask , Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA);

Bitmap maschera = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.width(), mask.height(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Bitmap gc_result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.width(), mask.height(), Config.ARGB_8888);


Utils.matToBitmap(mask, maschera);
Utils.matToBitmap(dst, gc_result);

String maskpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
        + "grubcut_dst.png";

Highgui.imwrite(maskpath, dst);
```

thanks to all!!!

Comment: " it is true that core.add () takes only 1 channel ? " - no.

Comment: so why this error?
OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in void cv::arithm_op(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::InputArray, int, void (**)(const uchar*, size_t, const uchar*, size_t, uchar*, size_t, cv::Size, void*), bool, void*), file /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp

Comment: and if i use 
Imgproc.cvtColor(background, background, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY); on all Mat, Core.add work.
how can I convert the result in rgb? 
Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR); doesn't work